# Convert epoch time in UTC to epoch time in another Timezone

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I need to convert epoch time in UTC to epoch time in different timezone. Example : 1389556017000 in UTC to epoch time in America/Tijuana timezone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Long epoch_date = 1389556017000L;

        ZonedDateTime date1= Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch_date)
                             .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana"));

        long epoch_second = date1.toInstant().toEpochMilli();

       System.out.println("Epoch time in new timezone is  :" + epoch_second);
    }
```

My output is same as the input...

Comment: Of course, the output is same as the input. You are doing a lossless conversion from an instant to a zoned datetime and back to an instant. The point of time you are referencing, does not change. What kind of change do you expect?

Comment: Basically I want a new epoch time corresponding to the timezone specified. My incoming epoch time is always in UTC.

Comment: There is no such thing as “epoch time corresponding to the timezone”. The epoch is a fixed point of time and other points of time, specified as number of milliseconds that have been elapsed since the epoch, do not change. The whole purpose of this kind of time representation is that it is universal, independent of things like timezones or local calendars.

Comment: Input : 1389556017000L
UTC Timestamp : 2014-01-12T19:46:57Z[UTC]
America/Tijuana timestamp : 2014-01-12T11:46:57-08:00.... Now i want the epoch time since America/Tijuana timezone... The time difference in about 7 hours.. So i should ideally get lesser number than the input..

Comment: No, there is no time difference between these dates. Your local clocks show different numbers, but it is still the same point of time. Either, you want to refer to the point of time, that’s what epoch millis about, or you want to refer to local representations. Mixing these two concepts makes no sense.

Comment: @Holger you are right for epoch time. But if i want a corresponding Long value in miiliseconds for America/Tijuana timestamp : 2014-01-12T11:46:57-08:00. . How can I get that?

Comment: Corresponding to what? The difference between this time and the reference point still is the same.

Comment: The epoch as a number is always `0`.  The Unix Epoch is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` - the `Z` indicates UTC. Thus unix timestamps are *always* UTC based.  `toEpochMili` returns the milliseconds *since* the epoch. The terminology "epoch time" is invalid. https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Answer (score 5):

Epoch time is an absolute point in time.
It is not relative to any timezone.

Eg - 6:30 PM in India is same as 1:00 PM in England.
**The Epoch for both the times is the same.**

You can read up more at - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch

Answer (score 3):

2014-01-12T11:46:57-08:00 and 2014-01-12T19:46:57Z are the *same time* (call it T1).

1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (i.e., the start of the epoch) and 1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00 (call it T0) are the *same time*.

Times are internally stored as the number of seconds, milliseconds, whatever, between T0 and the time in question.

There is only one answer to the number of seconds, milliseconds, whatever, between T1 and T0.